# Glassfish can't find activerecord-jdbc-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, glassfish, jruby, warbler

I'm trying to deploy simple Rails app on glassfish v3 and get the following error:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: Could not find RubyGem activerecord-jdbc-adapter (>= 0)
```

Environment details:
App is packaged as war using warbler.
JRuby 1.4.0 installed locally, with activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem installed.
App is configured to use derby database (migration is successful):

```
development:
      host: localhost
      adapter: jdbc
      driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
      url: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/railsdb
      username: rails
      password: rails
```

System: Mac OS 10.6.2

Comment: I would encourage you to deploy your rails app onto v3 'native' instead of packing it up into a war file...  You can find info about doing that in the hits returned by this search: http://www.google.com/search?q=glassfish+v3+deploy+rails+app

Comment: If you do install the war file, it has jruby.jar inside of the war, so you don't need to install all of that stuff on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you need to tell Warbler to include the gem in the war file. You can do this by either adding the gem to your config/environment.rb as follows:

```
config.gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter", :lib => false
```

Or by ensuring you have a Warbler configuration file ('warble config') and adding the following entry:

```
config.gems << "activerecord-jdbc-adapter"
```